# The ${ myObj.getDescription() } don't return anything

Tags: jsp, tomcat

In my JSP page, I import an object:

```
<% Label label= (Label) session.getAttribute("label"); %>
```

then inside a form input, I have:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control"  name="description" value="${label.getDescription()}" required>
```

where the `label.getDescription()` returns a string. However nothing is printed in my form. If I change it with `<%=label.getDescription()%>` then it works. Why the `${label.getDescription()}` doesn't work? I used it before and it worked fine...

Answer (score 0):

You could use the EL implicit `sessionScope` to get attributes from the session:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="description" 
       value="${sessionScope.label.description}" required />
```

And skip the scriptlet altogether.